# Adjusting the distance of a swipe event in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe

Is it possible to adjust the distance that is necessary to trigger the swipe event, and if so how is it done?.

Here the code im talking about:

```
$('.page2').bind('swiperight', function(event, ui){
    $.mobile.changePage(
        $('.page1'),
        {
          allowSamePageTransition: true,
          transition: 'slide',
          reverse: 'true', 
          showLoadMsg: false,                    
          reloadPage: true,
        }
    );
    return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You need to modify these properties:

- `$.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold (default: 30px)` – Swipe horizontal displacement must be more than this.
- `$.event.special.swipe.verticalDistanceThreshold (default: 75px)` – Swipe vertical displacement must be less than this.

This must be done during the **[mobileinit](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/api/globalconfig.html)** event, like this:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold (default: 30px);
    $.event.special.swipe.verticalDistanceThreshold (default: 75px);
});
```

One last thing. If you have never worked with **[mobileinit](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/api/globalconfig.html)**, this event must be called before jQuery mobile is initialized, like this:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
        $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold (default: 30px);
        $.event.special.swipe.verticalDistanceThreshold (default: 75px);
    });
</script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

Take a look at the official documentation [here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/)

Comment: $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold = value; Did the trick :) Thx